# Write $u = u_1 + u_2$ where $u_1$ is parallel to $v$ and $u_2$ is orthogonal to $v$

Tags: linear-algebra

$u = \left[\begin{array}{c}
3 \\
-2 \\
1\end{array}\right]$

$v = \left[\begin{array}{c}
4 \\
1 \\
1\end{array}\right]$

So first I thought that since $u_1$ is parallel to $v$, then $u_1 = v$. Since $u_2$ is orthogonal to $v$, then $u_2 \cdot v = 0$, and I solve for $u_2$.

$u_2 = \left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-2 \\
-2\end{array}\right]$

So $u = \left[\begin{array}{c}
4 \\
1 \\
1\end{array}\right] +  \left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-2 \\
-2\end{array}\right]$

Is this correct?

Comment: So then you must find scalars $c_1,c_2$ such that $u = c_1\left[\begin{array}{c}
4 \\
1 \\
1\end{array}\right] + c_2 \left[\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-2 \\
-2\end{array}\right]$
Which is basically a system with three equations and two unknowns

Comment: Ohh forgot about the scalar multiples. Thanks.

Comment: @EA304GT $\pmatrix{1 \\ -2 \\ -2}$ is not the only vector orthogonal to $v$ so that equation might not (and in fact definitely doesn't) have any solutions.

Comment: @fossdeep You won't be able to solve that equation.  See my answer for two methods you *can* use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector you chose for $u_2$ isn't the only vector orthogonal to $v$.  There is in fact a *plane* of vectors orthogonal to $v$ so here are two methods you can use to figure this out:

---

To find $u_1$ you need to find the projection of $u$ onto $\operatorname{span}(v)$.  The formula for that is $$\operatorname{proj}_v u = \frac{u\cdot v}{v\cdot v}v$$

That formula will get you $u_1$, then to find $u_2$ you can just subtract:

$$u=u_1+u_2 \\ \implies u_2 = u-u_1$$

This method is called the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

---

Or... if we want a method a little closer to yours, we just need a basis for the vectors orthogonal to $v$.  That subspace is $2$-dimensional, so you just need $1$ more vector orthogonal to $v$ that is not a multiple of the vector you already found.  Let's rename those guesses you made for $u_1$ and $u_2$ (because they're not completely correct).  We'll call them $\tilde u_1=\pmatrix{4 \\ 1 \\ 1}$ and $\tilde u_2=\pmatrix{1 \\ -2 \\ -2}$ instead.  Then the other vector orthogonal to $v$ that you find will be $\tilde u_3$.

Then you just need to solve $$u=c_1\tilde u_1 + c_2\tilde u_2 + c_3\tilde u_3$$  Once you've found the $c_1, c_2$, and $c_3$, then the answer will just be $$u_1 = c_1\tilde u_1 \\ u_2 = c_2\tilde u_2 + c_3\tilde u_3$$